# How to add quiz to video in kaltura kmc editor on vpaas?

Tags: video

I looked at tutorials, but I don't see the quiz button in the toolbar on the left, only "advertisement" button.

Answer (score 0):

You don't add quiz to video.

Instead, you create a video quiz by selecting Add New, then Video Quiz

The [Kaltura knowledge pages](https://knowledge.kaltura.com/kaltura-video-editing-tools-quiz-tab) on this give you a full tutorial, and should be your first stop for this sort of thing.

Comment: Is this available with the free account?